# Find $y$ for $y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = (\sqrt[y]{y})^y$ where $y$ is a positive real number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the answer in the textbook with which I disagree / don't understand:
$$y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = (\sqrt[y]{y})^y$$
$$y^{y^{\frac{3}{2}}} = (y^{\frac{3}{2}})^y = y^{\frac{3}{2}y}$$
Comparing indices, we get:
$$y^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{3}{2}y$$
from $y^{\frac{1}{2}} = {\frac{3}{2}}$, we get: $$y = {\frac{9}{4}}$$
Here what I came up with:
$$y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = (\sqrt[y]{y})^y$$
$$(\sqrt[y]{y})^y = (y^{\frac{1}{y}})^y = y$$
$$y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = y \Rightarrow \sqrt[y]{y} = 1$$
And I get stuck somewhere around: $y = 1^y$

Comment: $y^{y^{3/2}}=(y^{3/2})^y$ doesn't necessarily hold.

Comment: Continuing from $y=1^y$, since $1^y=1$ for all $y>0$, thus $y=1^y=1$.

Comment: You're correct: your textbook is wrong.

Comment: Note that $$y^{y^{3/2}}\neq y^{3y/2}=(y^{3/2})^y$$

Comment: Where does $\frac32$ come from?

Comment: @Henry I have been asking myself the same question.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I missed that, my bad, thanks.

Comment: Is the original question $y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = (\sqrt[y]{y})^y$ or $y^{y \sqrt{y}} = (y \sqrt{y})^y$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive $y$ you have  $(\sqrt[y]{y})^y = y$

so $y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = (\sqrt[y]{y})^y\implies y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = y \implies y^{\sqrt[y]{y}-1} = 1$

so either $y=1$ or $\sqrt[y]{y}-1=0$

in both cases implying $y=1$

---

Alternatively if the original question is actually $y^{y \sqrt{y}} = (y \sqrt{y})^y$

Then this indeed gives $y^{y^{3/2}}=y^{3y/2}$

so either $y=1$ or $y^{3/2}=\frac{3y}{2}$

i.e. either $y=1$ or $y^{1/2}=\frac{3}{2}$

i.e. either $y=1$ or $y=\frac{9}{4}$

Comment: For the alternative case, can you explain further please, I am getting confused, how do you come up with $\frac {3}{2}$ ?

Comment: @phi reading $y \sqrt{y}$ as $y\times \sqrt{y}=y^1\times y^{1/2}=y^{3/2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$y^{\sqrt[y]{y}} = (\sqrt[y]{y})^y\implies \sqrt[y]{y}\ln y=y\ln \sqrt[y]{y}=\ln y\implies (\sqrt[y]{y}-1)\ln y=0\implies y=1 $$

Comment: ... which is a bit questionable because you simplify lightheartedly by something possibly null (log(y)).

Comment: Is the use of logarithm necessary here ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Is this better?

Comment: Indeed, much more  (+1)

Comment: @phi1.614 It is not necessary but I find it easier to deal with logarithms than powers of roots.